# glDrawElements() draw my .obj models wrong

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm having a problem with the "glDrawElements" function in OpenGL. When drawing the model with the function I'm seeing artifacts:

[image: postimg.org/image/wcbjnp93r/ (the image.)]

I didn't add any light or texture.

I wrote a class with C++:

```
//The obj-catcher.h
//Just ignore the Chinese in the code....
#include <gl\glut.h>
#include <gl\glaux.h>
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"cstdio"
#include"math.h"
#include"time.h"
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024 //å­ç¬¦ä¸²å¤å¶æå¤§é¿åº¦

AUX_RGBImageRec *LoadBMP(char *Filename)                // Loads A Bitmap Image
{
    FILE *File=NULL;                                    // File Handle

    if (!Filename)                                      // Make Sure A Filename Was Given
    {
        return NULL;                                    // If Not Return NULL
    }
    File=fopen(Filename,"r");                           // Check To See If The File Exists
    if (File)                                           // Does The File Exist?
    {
        fclose(File);                                   // Close The Handle
        return auxDIBImageLoad(Filename);               // Load The Bitmap And Return A Pointer
    }

    return NULL;                                        // If Load Failed Return NULL
}
int LoadGLTextures(int num,char *dir,unsigned int * texture)                    // Load Bitmaps And Convert To Textures å è½½çå¾ååªè½æ¯2çå¹
{
    int Status=FALSE;                                   // Status Indicator
    AUX_RGBImageRec *TextureImage[1];                   // Create Storage Space For The Texture
    memset(TextureImage,0,sizeof(TextureImage));        // Set The Pointer To NULL
    // Load The Bitmap, Check For Errors, If Bitmap's Not Found Quit
    if (TextureImage[0]=LoadBMP(dir))
    {
        Status=TRUE;                                    // Set The Status To TRUE
        glGenTextures(1, &texture[num]);                // Create The Texture
        // Typical Texture Generation Using Data From The Bitmap
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[num]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, TextureImage[0]->sizeX, TextureImage[0]->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, TextureImage[0]->data);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    }
    if (TextureImage[0])                                    // If Texture Exists
    {
        if (TextureImage[0]->data)                          // If Texture Image Exists
            free(TextureImage[0]->data);                    // Free The Texture Image Memory
        free(TextureImage[0]);                              // Free The Image Structure
    }
    return Status;                                      // Return The Status
}
typedef struct vertex
{
    GLfloat pos[3];//ä¾æ¬¡æ¯x,y,z
}vertex;
typedef struct vertexnormals
{
    GLfloat io[3];
}vertexnormals;
typedef struct texturecoords
{
    GLfloat io[3];
}texturecoords;
typedef struct vertexindex
{
    unsigned int Vertex[3];
}vertexindex;
bool fco(FILE *file)
{
    if(fclose(file)!=0)
    {
        perror("fclose");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return true;
}
bool getSurface(char *src,vertexindex &vindex)//get surface
{
    if(src[0]!='f'||src[1]!=' ') return false;
    int i;
    int result=0;
    for(i=1;i==' ';i++);i++;
    for(;;i++)
    {
        if(src[i]==' ') break;
        if(src[i]=='/')
            break;
        else
        {
            result*=10;
            result+=src[i]-48;
        }
    }
    vindex.Vertex[0]=result-1;
    for(;;i++) if(src[i]==' ') break;
    for(;i==' ';i++);i++;
    result=0;
    for(;;i++)
    {
        if(src[i]==' ') break;
        if(src[i]=='/') break;
        else
        {
            result*=10;
            result+=src[i]-48;
        }
    }
    vindex.Vertex[1]=result-1;
    for(;;i++) if(src[i]==' ') break;
    for(;i==' ';i++);i++;
    result=0;
    for(;;i++)
    {
        if(src[i]==' '||src[i]=='\0'||src[i]=='\n') break;
        if(src[i]=='/')
            break;
        else
        {
            result*=10;
            result+=src[i]-48;
        }
    }
    vindex.Vertex[2]=result-1;
    return true;
}
bool getVertex(char *src,vertex &dir)//some shit in here|add:->the shit is done
{

    int i;
    bool flag[3];
    bool pc[3];
    double result=0;
    int db=0;
    bool floa;
    memset(flag,0,sizeof(flag));//æ¥åç¹åæ å®æåº¦å¤æ­
    memset(pc,0,sizeof(pc));//æ­£è´å¤æ­
    if(src[0]!='v'||src[1]!=' ')
        return false;
    else
    {
        floa=false;
        for(i=1;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°vä¹åç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[0]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[0]) result=-result; 
        dir.pos[0]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[1]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[1]) result=-result; 
        dir.pos[1]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') break;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[2]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[2]) result=-result; 
        dir.pos[2]=result; 
        return true;
    }
}
bool getVertexNormals(char *src,vertexnormals &dir)
{
    int i;
    bool flag[2];
    bool pc[3];
    double result=0;
    int db=0;
    bool floa;
    memset(flag,0,sizeof(flag));
    memset(pc,0,sizeof(pc));
    if(!(src[0]=='v'&&src[1]=='n'&&src[2]==' '))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        floa=false;
        for(i=1;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°vä¹åç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[0]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[0]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[0]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[1]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[1]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[1]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') break;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[2]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[2]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[2]=result; 
        return true;
    }
}
bool getTextureCoords(char *src,texturecoords &dir)
{
    int i;
    bool flag[2];
    bool pc[3];
    double result=0;
    int db=0;
    bool floa;
    memset(flag,0,sizeof(flag));
    memset(pc,0,sizeof(pc));
    if(!(src[0]=='v'&&src[1]=='t'&&src[2]==' '))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        floa=false;
        for(i=1;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°vä¹åç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[0]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[0]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[0]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') return false;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[1]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[1]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[1]=result; 
        for(;src[i+1]==' ';i++);i++;//æ¾å°ç¬¬ä¸ä¸ªæ°æ®ä¹åç¬¬äºä¸ªæ°æ®ä½ç½®
        floa=false;
        db=0;
        result=0;
        for(;;i++)
        {
            if(src[i]=='\n'||src[i]=='\0') break;
            if(src[i]==' ')
                break;
            if(src[i]=='-')
                pc[2]=true;
            if(src[i]<=57&&src[i]>=48)
            {
                if(!floa)
                {
                    result*=10;
                    result+=src[i]-48;
                }
                else
                {
                    result+=(src[i]-48)*pow(10.0,--db);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(src[i]=='.') floa=true;
            }
        }
        if(pc[2]) result=-result; 
        dir.io[2]=result; 
        return true;
    }
}
bool getdir(char * dir,char * tem)
{
    int i,m=strlen(tem),num=0,j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        if(dir[i]=='\\')
            num++;
    }
    for(i=0,j=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        tem[i]=dir[i];
        if(dir[i]=='\\')
            j++;
        if(j==num)
            break;
    }
    tem[i+1]='\0';
    return true;
}
bool getmtl(char *src,FILE *fp,char * dir)
{
    int i,m=strlen(src),n;
    char  temp[100];
    if(m<6) return false;
    if(!(src[0]=='m'&&src[1]=='t'&&src[2]=='l'&&src[3]=='l'&&src[4]=='i'&&src[5]=='b'&&src[6]==' ')) return false;
    src[m-1]='\0';
    getdir(dir,temp);
    n=strlen(temp);
    for(i=n;i<m;i++)
        temp[i]=src[i-n+7];
    fp=fopen(temp,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        perror(temp);
        return false;
    }
    else
        printf("å¯¼å¥æè´¨åºæå :%s\n",temp);
    return true;
}
class Container
{
public:
    Container(char *fp)//ä½¿ç¨æ¶å¿é¡»ä¿è¯objä¸­æ¯è¡åªæä¸æ¡æä»¤
    {
        int t1,t2;
        t1=clock();
        int cur=0;
        int i[8]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        int vcur=0;
        int tcur=0;
        mtlfnum=0;
        VertexNumber=0;
        TriangleNumber=0;
        VertexNormals=0;
        TextureCoords=0;
        if((file=fopen(fp,"r"))==NULL)
        {
            perror(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("ç¬¬ä¸æ¬¡éåæä»¶é¢å¤çä¸­...\n");
        while(fgets(buffer,MAX_LINE_LENGTH,file)!=NULL)
        {
            cur++;
            if(buffer[0]=='#')
                continue;
            if(buffer[0]=='m'&&buffer[1]=='t'&&buffer[2]=='l'&&buffer[3]=='l'&&buffer[4]=='i'&&buffer[5]=='b'&&buffer[6]==' ')//ç±äº&&ç¬¦å·çç­è·¯æåºæä»¥ä¸ä¼éæ³è®¿é®åå­
                mtlfnum++;
            if(buffer[0]=='v'&&buffer[1]==' ')
                VertexNumber++;
            if(buffer[0]=='f')
                TriangleNumber++;
            if(buffer[0]=='v'&&buffer[1]=='n')
                VertexNormals++;
            if(buffer[0]=='v'&&buffer[1]=='t')
                TextureCoords++;
        }
        printf("ç¬¬ä¸æ¬¡é¢å¤çå·²ç»æ\nåå¾ä¿¡æ¯:æè´¨åºæ°:%d é¡¶ç¹æ°ï¼%d é¢æ°:%d æ³çº¿æ°ï¼%d çº¹çåæ æ°:%d\n",mtlfnum,VertexNumber,TriangleNumber,VertexNormals,TextureCoords);
        v=new vertex [VertexNumber];
        vn=new vertexnormals[VertexNormals];
        vt=new texturecoords[TextureCoords];
        vindex=new vertexindex[TriangleNumber];
        mtl=new FILE * [mtlfnum];
        fco(file);
        if((file=fopen(fp,"r"))==NULL)
        {
            perror(fp);
            exit(1);
        }
        cur=0;
        printf("æ­£å¨è¯»å¥æ¨¡åæ°æ®...\n");
        while(fgets(buffer,MAX_LINE_LENGTH,file)!=NULL)
        {
            cur++;
            if(i[0]<=VertexNumber)
                if(getVertex(buffer,v[i[0]]))
                    i[0]++;
            if(i[1]<=TriangleNumber)
                if(getSurface(buffer,vindex[i[1]]))
                    i[1]++;
            if(i[2]<=VertexNormals)
                if(getVertexNormals(buffer,vn[i[2]]))
                    i[2]++;
            if(i[3]<=TextureCoords)
                if(getTextureCoords(buffer,vt[i[3]]))
                    i[3]++;
            if(i[4]<=mtlfnum)
                if(getmtl(buffer,mtl[i[4]],fp))
                    i[4]++;
        }
        t2=clock();
        printf("è¯»å¥æ¨¡åæåï¼\nç¨æ¶%5d(ms)\n",t2-t1);
    }
    ~Container()
    {
        fco(file);
        if(v)
        {
            delete(v);
            v=NULL;
        }
        if(vt)
        {
            delete(vt);
            vt=NULL;
        }
        if(vn)
        {
            delete(vn);
            vn=NULL;
        }
        if(mtl)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<mtlfnum;i++)
                fco(mtl[i]);
            delete mtl;
            mtl=NULL;
        }
    }
    inline int get_tnum(){return TriangleNumber;}
    inline int get_vnum(){return VertexNumber;}
    inline int get_vnnum(){return VertexNormals;}
    inline int get_vtnum(){return TextureCoords;}
    inline vertex *             get_v() {return v;      }
    inline vertexnormals*       get_vn(){return vn;     }
    inline texturecoords*       get_vt(){return vt;     }
    inline vertexindex*         get_vi(){return vindex; }
private:
    FILE *file;
    int VertexNumber;
    int TriangleNumber;
    int VertexNormals;
    int mtlfnum;
    int TextureCoords;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    FILE **mtl;
    vertexindex *vindex;
    vertex *v;
    texturecoords *vt;
    vertexnormals *vn;
};
```

and

```
#include <Gl\glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include"obj-catcher.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
Container A("models\\SCAR.obj");
#define GL_PI 3.1415926f
#define bCull 1
#define bDepth 1
#define bOutline 1
double xRot=0.0f,yRot=0.0f,x=0.0f,y=0.0f,dx=0.8f,dy=1.0f;
GLfloat nRange=50.0f;
static GLfloat aspe;
unsigned int te[37];
GLuint sample=1;
void SetupRC()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);//单调着色
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,(float *)A.get_v());
    glNewList(sample,GL_COMPILE);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,A.get_tnum()*3,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,A.get_vi());
    glEndList();
}
void ChangeSize(GLsizei w,GLsizei h)
{
    if(h==0)
        h=1;
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    if(w<=h)
    {
        aspe=h/w;
        glOrtho(-nRange,nRange,-nRange*h/w,nRange*h/w,-nRange,nRange);
    }
    else
    {
        aspe=w/h;
        glOrtho(-nRange*w/h,nRange*w/h,-nRange,nRange,-nRange,nRange);
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void RenderScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glPushMatrix();
//  yRot++;
    if(yRot>360) yRot=0;
    glRotatef(xRot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(yRot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    glCallList(sample);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}
void processSpecialKeys(int key,int x,int y)//键位控制
{
    if(key==GLUT_KEY_UP)
        xRot--;
    if(key==GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
        xRot++;
    if(key==GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
        yRot++;
    if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
        yRot--;
    if(key==27)
        exit(1);
}
void TimerFunction(int value)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1,TimerFunction,1);
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    glutInit( &argc , argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutCreateWindow("caption");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);
    glutTimerFunc(1,TimerFunction,1);
    SetupRC();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Can you give me some advise to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of Open GL ?

Comment: I have not read the official one.But I am reading the book called OpenGLSuperBible these days.

Comment: visit this link www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml‎
maybe can support you, Good luck friend ....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like either your elements data or vertex data is not correct or miss-aligned between them. I have seen similar problems when you don't specify correctly the stride or offset on you vertex data. Post some code here about how you setup your elements and vertex arrays before calling glDrawElements.

TIP: Start small, for example with a Quad o a Cube, then move to a complex mesh, then add texturing and lighting.

Comment: Thanks for your patient help.However,I 've already post all the code through [codepad.org].The codes are at the two links.

Comment: Didn't notice those. I don't spot nothing wrong with your rendering side. Probably the problems is in loading your model, the other side is quite simple.

Comment: Em,I'm going to check the detail mistakes.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it without using a display list?

From Microsoft's documentation:

> You can include the glDrawElements function in display lists. When glDrawElements is included in a display list, the necessary array data (determined by the array pointers and enables) is also entered into the display list. Because the array pointers and enables are client-side state variables, their values affect display lists when the lists are created, not when the lists are executed.

Comment: I tried.If the model is as simple as a box.It would draw perfectly.But when the model is as complex as the SCAR.It would draw nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be index order. when you are reading faces from `obj`, just subtract 1 from each index because index starts from 1 not from 0.